# STM32 Uart reading issue

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, uart, serial-communication

The following code only reads up the first iteration. I don't seem to see the problem.

```c
void USART2_IRQHandler(void){

    if (USART_GetITStatus(USART_MODULE, USART_IT_RXNE) != RESET)
    {
        Rx_Buff[counter++] = (uint8_t)USART_ReceiveData(USART_MODULE);

        USART_ClearITPendingBit(USART_MODULE, USART_IT_RXNE);
    }
}

uint16_t uart_read(void *load, uint16_t size){

    uint8_t *u = (uint8_t *)load;
    uint8_t p = 0;
    if ((size <= counter))
    {

        for (uint16_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            u[i] = Rx_Buff[i];
        }
        return size;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "first iteration" mean exactly? You only seem to fill a buffer from 0 to growing indexes. If you do not reset `counter` at some time or wrap around in a ring buffer, you will run out of your buffer after a while. But we would need a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to see what really happens. Do you reset `counter` in some other function? How is it defined? Please edit your question to show a minimum but complete enough example.

Comment: @Gerhardh hello, thank you for answering, what i meant u[i] only gets filled with rx_buff[0], and nothing of the rest of the buffer

Comment: OK, that is a different thing. I don't know your MCU. Maybe you need to loop in your interrupt handler until there is no more data and only afterwards reset pending interrupt.

Answer (score 1):

Two potential issues here.

Firstly, you don't show how `counter` and `Rx_Buff` are defined. They will need to be `volatile` in order for the compiler to know that the interrupt can change it. Normally the compiler will assume that unless code which it can see is called changes a variable, it does not change. So for example, there is no need to read data from Rx_Buff because no non-interrupt code is writing to it. It can just assume that it was never written to, and is the default value (likely NULL characters).

Similarly, it might choose to eliminate the entire if() statement because as far as it can see, `counter` never changes. It's always the initial value of zero, and `size` can't be negative, so the if statement is always false.

Secondly, you don't need to clear the RXNE bit. It is cleared when you access the data register via `USART_ReceiveData()`. You can actually just read it directly out of the data register, you don't really need to call a function to do it.

Comment: `volatile` is not the problem here because `uart_read` is a function which might call in multiple place so compiler will not be allowed to optimized here. Additionally, the `counter` is access in interrupt and normal thread so there is also no problem with cache.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What you say doesn't negate the need for volatile.

Comment: it is not similar to case `while (size < counter)` which might optimize to check just 1 because compiler see that variable not change during execution. For this it is actually an `if` condition and will always need to evaluate every call. Event without `volatile` it also can not convert to a compare with a constant value.

Comment: @ThongDT yeah, I've elaborated on my original answer to explain this more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-activate the uart interrupt after receiving each byte. Probably that's why only the first byte is read.

Somewhere in your `main()` you have activated uart receive interrupt. Repeat the same line in your ISR after reading the byte.

The HAL library function for activating uart receive interrupt is `HAL_UART_Receive_IT` (I guess you have not used HAL libraries in your code) which generates a interrupt after receiving each byte and needs to be re-activated in the interrupt callback.

Answer (score 0):

There are some points to check here:

- Check the value of `counter` to make sure that your code could receive sufficient data that you expected.
- Value of `counter` and `size` at the time you calling API `uart_read` because at following line you check the condition:

  ```
   if ((size <= counter))
  ```

If you haven't received enough data, it will not able to perform further copy. Actually, function `uart_read` will return `undefined value` if `size` > `counter`.

- Assuming that you perform clear `counter` value and wait until received `size` bytes then perform further process. In this case, you might need to loop `uart_read` multiple time until it return to your expected `size` value.

Additionally, you should consider again the usage of `counter`, `Rx_Buff` to avoid the case `counter` grow so big.

Answer (score 0):

The counter always inc, but the you always read from beginning of buffer which is wrong. You have to store the previous read offset globally (similar to count).
E.g:

1. assume count = 1000 bytes
2. 1st read 20 bytes `i` must starts from 0...19
3. 2nd read 20 bytes, `i` must starts from 20...39